# Android McalendarView

Tags: android

I trying to use mcalendarview in my project but in my xml layout file it doesn't show anything on design tab in android studio.

[image: screenshot of my project]

Answer (score 0):

Custom view are sometimes not get render in view tab. But don't worry, they will be render at runtime.

Comment: i tried running my project but i could not run,logcat is empty,whats going on with mcalendarview

Comment: Actually logcat empty is something different problem. So remove calenderview and try to get log first. Then try for calenderview. So u can rid off this easily

Comment: i tried running it an emulator nothing displayed and on real device nothing to..,anyone with expertise on this please help

Comment: Thanks @Dharvik shah,the problem is fixed now and it was because i used "public class ChecksafetyActivity extends Activity “ 
 insted of 
 "public class ChecksafetyActivity extends AppCompatActivity“